# hyphen after an open compund noun for a hierarchical two-level compund noun

Tags: hyphens, compound-nouns

EDIT: The sentence is what I would consider a minimum working example and is originally followed by some subordinate clause. I am not looking to simply reduce word count but to improve intelligibility without rephrasing. If there is no legal way to do that, that's fine. What I am looking for is a either the correct way of hyphenating this noun, "No, that doesn't work" or "Fun fact: here's why you cannot do everything you can do with a simple noun with an open compound noun, like making it the first component of a closed compound noun."

---

I am writing my master's thesis and I regularly stumble across situations where I want to use the word "rigid body" as the first component of a compound noun.

An example is the following:

> There are kinematic chains of rigid body linked revolute joints.

meaning:

> There are kinematic chains which consist of revolute joints which in turn are linked by rigid bodies.

My intuition would be "rigid body-linked" but that makes it even less readable.

Personally, I am at war with using the - apparently correct - orthography of "rigid body" over "rigidbody", as there is no inherent disambiguation between the well defined mathematical construct and the colloquial term for, well, a body that's rigid.

In Germany, where we know no shame when it comes to compound words and can

append and append
to our hearts' content
with no need to repent, :D

I would just draw two components together and write "rigidbody-linked".

Any suggestions on what's correct here?

P.S.:
I believe that **There are kinematic chains of rigid body linked revolute joints** is correct, but it makes me uneasy that someone could interpret this as claiming the existence of revolute franchise locations which could be linked to a criminal syndicate of the name "chains of rigid body".

Comment: link requires the preposition **to**. Also: compound

Answer (score 1):

If you take your gloss phrase (after *meaning:*) and remove unnecessary stuff, you have a clear, compact expression:
**There are kinematic chains of revolute joints linked by rigid bodies.**

That has only one more word than the phrase giving rise to doubts.

Comment: Yeah, but does one really need there are?? Kinematic chains of revolute joints link rigid bodies.